# Migration of npm config between npm v8 and npm v9

Tags: npm, github-actions, nexus, npm-publish

I migrated from `node 16.19.1` with npm version of `8.19.1` into node `20.5.1` with npm version `9.8.0` in my github actions workflows which publishes npm into Nexus repository with version OSS 3.41.1.

My initial config for npm v8.19.1 was as below:

```
npm config set registry="http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/example-package/"
npm config set _auth="MY_BASE_64_TOKEN"
npm config set email="my.project@mail.com"
npm config set always-auth=true
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

And with this config I could successfully execute `npm publish`

npm v9 introduced breaking changes which affected my config, for example:

- `always-auth` is is not a valid npm option
- `_auth` cannot be used as npm config - it must be part of URL registry
- `auth-type` changed default value from `legacy` to `web`

So I changed my config to:

```
npm config set email="my.project@mail.com"
npm config set strict-ssl=false
npm config set auth-type=legacy
npm config set registry="http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/example-package/"
npm config set //nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/example-package/:_auth=MY_BASE_64_TOKEN
```

and after `npm publish` I have those errors:

```
npm verb Linux 5.15.0-1041-azure
npm verb node v20.5.1
npm verb npm  v9.8.0
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
npm verb exit 1
npm verb code 1
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Hello
as you noticed `npm` v9 introduced breaking changes. I encountered your same issues on my **GitLab CI** environment but I managed to overcome them by implementing the steps described below.
Before showing the steps that I followed, I would like to stress out that the identified solution is based on [authentication using basic auth](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/npm-registry/npm-security#npmSecurity-AuthenticationUsingBasicAuth), plus it has been tested for the systems and platforms illustrated below:

- `node:18.18.0` Docker image
- **Sonatype Nexus Repository** OSS 3.59.0-01
- `npm v9.8.1`

Referring to your parameters, the steps to be implemented are reported below:

- `echo "email=my.project@mail.com" > /root/.npmrc`
- `echo "always-auth=true" > /root/.npmrc`
- `echo "//nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/_auth=<username:password>" > /root/.npmrc`
- `npm publish --registry=http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/repository/example-package/`

**Watch out!** As stated by the official documentation, `<username:password>` value must be expressed as **base64-encoding**.

Finally, I actually see that you are accessing the registry via **HTTP** and not via **HTTPS**, consequently I imagine that in your case you need the additional step:

- `echo "strict-ssl=false" > /root/.npmrc`

Even though, I am not quite sure about it, since in my case, my company's registry was exposed via **HTTPS**.